# Translating "loudly" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

Consider the following translation:

> Estabas cantando en voz alta en la ducha.
>
> You were singing loudly in the shower.

Is it correct? I mean is this how a native speaker would translate the sentence in a regular/colloquial conversation? Please provide your country in the answer to help me/others understand if there's any dialectical variation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm from Northern Spain)

`loud` in English usually means high volume. That is `alto` in Spanish, (or sometimes `fuerte`, particularly if it can be confused with high tone or pitch, which is also `alto`).

But the expression `en voz alta` has a subtler meaning: it is not `loudly`, but just using normal speak volume, I think it would be `aloud`, or `out loud`:

> Lee el periódico en voz alta. - Read the newspaper aloud.

So:

> Estabas cantando en voz alta en la ducha.

would be:

> You were singing aloud in the shower.

While:

> You were singing loudly in the shower.

would be:

> Estabas cantando (muy) alto en la ducha.

Comment: `Ruidosamente` is an alternative.

Comment: @dockeryz: But `ruidosamente`, talking about singing, has a negative meaning (`ruido` is `noise`).

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not an alternative.  The OP never mentioned needing a positive or negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation and how to addressed the Audience. I would personally use ...

**You were singing loudly in the shower.**

**-Tu estabas cantando en voz alta en la Regadera**

friendly approach slang 
**Tu estabas cantando escandalosamente en la regadera**

Here's the part where you used Escandaloso/escandalosamente,Only when you are going to refer to an individual as lazy(I know people in the field that refer to them as loud as a niece way and supposedly professional)

Example...

**John is very loudly when it comes work**

**John es bien escandaloso cuando se requiere trabajar**

In this above example you wouldn't use High Voice but rather Escandaloso. I grew at a community where people had little education so individuals refer to others as loud when they really meant lazy . I grew at the outskirt of Michoacan Mexico.

Comment: "John is very loud when it comes work" would be the usual expression. Loud used as an adjective, loudly as an adverb not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I have also heard people use `recio`to mean loudly. `Estabas cantando muy recio...`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the input...which country have you heard recio being used in? Just wanna understand if it has a regional nuance.

Comment: Mexicans here in the USA. I was in a band with some. Recio was used for fast or loud.